# Visual studio regex pattern does not work : ^.*Foo[^.,]\(+.*$

Tags: regex, visual-studio

I have following lines of code ,

```
int Foo(char);

int Foo()
{
//do something
}

int FooBar(char, char);
foo.Get();
fooBar.Get();
m_FooBar.Get();
case foo:
fooBar(x,y);
```

I want to search only for function reference, declaration and definition with 'Foo' name. Only four of the above lines to be shown in result

1. int Foo(char);
2. int Foo()
3. int FooBar(char, char);
4. fooBar(x,y);

I tried

`^.*Foo[^.,]\(+.*$`

But it also selected ***case Foo:***

Whats wrong with this regex?

Comment: `^.*Foo\w*\(+.*` should work.

Comment: Character class `[^.,]` matches also new line, thus `case Foo` is matched. I recommend using `\w` instead

Comment: wow, thank you Wiktor and Michal. Now it all makes sense. I will post this as an answer.

Comment: We can post our solutions ourselves, please remove your comment answer.

Comment: Okay, please post it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
^.*Foo\w*\(+.*$
```

Make sure you make it case insensitive, as shown in [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dSU5Z9/1).
The `[^.,]` part is a negated character class, and it matches any char that is not a dot and comma, it might match a line break char. With `\w`, you only match `[A-Za-z0-9_]` characters.

**Details**

- `^` - start of string (line in text editors)
- `.*` - any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as many as possible
- `Foo` - a `Foo` word
- `\w*` - 0 or more letters, digits, `_`s
- `\(+` -  1 or more `(` chars
- `.*` - any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as many as possible
- `$` - end of string (line in text editors).

Comment: Thank you.
This also means we can try out ^.*Foo[^.,\r\n]\(+.*$ where [^.,\r\n] will exclude carriage return along with dot  and comma .